# Maze 2D Recursive Algorithm Issue

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, maze

I've been trying to make a program that could solve a maze recursively. But I have an issue with my recursion in my algorithm method. The algorithm can only solve as far as one position for the solution.

Here's it on console:

*Note "char indicators" for the 2D array:*

- '*' = walls
- '#' = start
- '$' = end
- ' ' = possible path/not a wall
- '@' = path
- '~' = deadend

Desired output:

```
Presolved maze:
* * * * * * * * * * 
* # * * * * * * * * 
*   *           * * 
*   *       *   * * 
*       *   *   * * 
* * *       *   * * 
* *     *   *   * * 
* *     *   *     * 
* * * * * * *     * 
*               $ * 
* * * * * * * * * * 

Maze solution:

* * * * * * * * * * 
* # * * * * * * * * 
* @ * @ @ @ @ @ * * 
* @ * @ ~ ~ * @ * * 
* @ @ @ * ~ * @ * * 
* * * ~ ~ ~ * @ * * 
* * ~ ~ * ~ * @ * * 
* * ~ ~ * ~ * @ ~ * 
* * * * * * * @ ~ * 
* ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ @ $ * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

Output I get:

```
Presolved maze:
* * * * * * * * * * 
* # * * * * * * * * 
*   *           * * 
*   *       *   * * 
*       *   *   * * 
* * *       *   * * 
* *     *   *   * * 
* *     *   *     * 
* * * * * * *     * 
*               $ * 
* * * * * * * * * * 

Maze solution:

* * * * * * * * * * 
* # * * * * * * * * 
* @ *           * * 
*   *       *   * * 
*       *   *   * * 
* * *       *   * * 
* *     *   *   * * 
* *     *   *     * 
* * * * * * *     * 
*               $ * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

I've tried other solutions such as removing the recursion within the recursion within my general case but that just regressed the minor progress that my algorithm could do (which is find one position). I was wondering what else I could do instead to fix this problem? The other methods work but the method "algorithm" doesn't work like how I would like it to work.

```
import java.util.*;
public class maze {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        allocateMaze();
    }
    
    public static void allocateMaze() {
        char[][] mazeArr = {{'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},//0
                            {'*','#','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},//1
                            {'*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*'},//2
                            {'*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*'},//3
                            {'*',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*'},//4
                            {'*','*','*',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*'},//5
                            {'*','*',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*'},//6
                            {'*','*',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*'},//7
                            {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ','*'},//8
                            {'*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','$','*'},//9
                            {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'}};//10
        
        //setting row and col to 0 for display method
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        System.out.println("Presolved maze:");
        displayMaze(mazeArr, row, col); //displays presolved maze
        row = 1;
        col = 1;
        boolean isSolved = false;
        System.out.println("\nMaze solution:");
        algorithm(mazeArr, row, col, isSolved); //create variable for solved maze, sends maze allocation to method that solves the maze
        System.out.println();
        row = 0;
        col = 0;
        displayMaze(mazeArr, row, col); //displays traced + solved maze
    }

    public static void displayMaze(char[][] mazeArr, int row, int col) {
        if (row < mazeArr.length) { //iterate through all (11) rows
            if (col < mazeArr[row].length) { //iterate through all (11) columns
                System.out.print(mazeArr[row][col] + " "); //displays the current index in the array
                displayMaze(mazeArr, row, col+1); //repeats this method by iterating through the columns first
                return;
            }
            System.out.println(); //enters the line after each row for display purposes
            displayMaze(mazeArr, row+1, col=0); //repeats this method by iterating through the rows
        }
    }
    
    public static char[][] algorithm(char[][] mazeArr, int row, int col, boolean isSolved){
        boolean isPath = false; // assume there is no path

        if (mazeArr[row][col] == '$' && isSolved == true) { // IF MAZE IS COMPLETELY SOLVED
            return mazeArr;

        } else { // IF MAZE IS NOT COMPLETELY SOLVED
            
            if (isSolved == false && isPath == false) { // start searching thru the maze, assume there is no path
                // THERE IS NO DEAD END
                
                if (mazeArr[row - 1][col] == ' ') { // if north has a path
                    mazeArr[row - 1][col] = '@'; // block off path to not go back here again
                    isPath = true; // there is a path
                    isSolved = false; // assume maze is still not solved
                    
                    return algorithm(mazeArr, row--, col, isSolved); // repeat process going to next north spot
                }
                
                if (mazeArr[row][col + 1] == ' ') { // if east has a path
                    mazeArr[row][col + 1] = '@'; // block off path to not go back here again
                    isPath = true; // there is a path
                    isSolved = false; // assume maze is still not solved

                    return algorithm(mazeArr, row, col++, isSolved); // repeat process going to next east spot
                }
                
                if (mazeArr[row + 1][col] == ' ') { // if south has a path
                    mazeArr[row + 1][col] = '@'; // block off path to not go back here again
                    isPath = true; // there is a path
                    isSolved = false; // assume maze is still not solved
                    
                    return algorithm(mazeArr, row++, col, isSolved); // repeat process going to next south spot
                }
                
                if (mazeArr[row][col - 1] == ' ') { // if west has a path
                    mazeArr[row][col - 1] = '@'; // block off path to not go back here again
                    isPath = true; // there is a path
                    isSolved = false; // assume maze is still not solved
                    
                    return algorithm(mazeArr, row, col--, isSolved); // repeat process going to next west spot
                }
                
                if (mazeArr[row][col] == '$') { // if you have reached the end of the maze
                    isSolved = true; // maze has been solved
                    
                    
                    return algorithm(mazeArr, row, col, isSolved); // algorithm will recognize
                }

            } else { // finds alternate path if there's a dead end
                if (mazeArr[row][col] != '#') {
                mazeArr[row][col] = '~'; //indicates that this index is a dead end
                }
                
                if (isPath == false) {
                    if (mazeArr[row - 1][col] == '@' && mazeArr[row - 1][col] != '#') { // if north was a path
                        isPath = true; 
                        isSolved = false;
                        
                        return algorithm(mazeArr, row--, col, isSolved); //returns to initial position before hitting dead end
                    }
                }
                
                if (isPath == false) {
                    if (mazeArr[row][col+1] == '@' && mazeArr[row][col+1] != '#') { // if east was a path
                        isPath = true; 
                        isSolved = false;
                        
                        return algorithm(mazeArr, row, col++, isSolved); //returns to initial position before hitting dead end
                    }
                }
                
                if (isPath == false) {
                    if (mazeArr[row + 1][col] == '@' && mazeArr[row + 1][col] != '#') { // if south was a path
                        isPath = true; 
                        isSolved = false;
                        
                        return algorithm(mazeArr, row++, col, isSolved); //returns to initial position before hitting dead end
                    }
                }
                
                if (isPath == false) {
                    if (mazeArr[row][col-1] == '@' && mazeArr[row][col-1] != '#') { // if west was a path
                        isPath = true; 
                        
                        return algorithm(mazeArr, row, col--, isSolved); //returns to initial position before hitting dead end
                    }
                }
                
                if (isPath == false) { // if there's no way out, that means there is no solution
                    System.out.println("No Solution");              
                    return mazeArr;
                }
                
            }
            return mazeArr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the program to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: I think `isPath` is the wrong sort of logic. Can you explain what that is?

Comment: @Neil  `isPath` is used to indicate if there is a path or not, it allows the algorithm to understand if there is no path going NESW so that the algorithm can check the dead end part of the code, hence the condition `(isSolved == false && isPath == false)`. if `isPath` still remains false within the recursion in recursion that means the path that the algorithm was going through was a dead end, it goes to the else structure which finds a way back from the dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `++` or `--` before `row` or `col` on when you recall `algorithm()`. When one of these comes after a variable, the variable gets incremented, but not the value that comes out:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        int y = x++;
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

gives

```
6 5
```

Above `x++` incremented `x`, but `y` was set to value of `x` before. To fix it put the increment before the variable, like `++row`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        int y = ++x;
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

output:

```
6 6
```